# Не могу сменить диск в командной строке. Где ошибка?

Tags: cmd

[image: скрин 2]Не могу сменить диск в командной стоке. В пределах диска - норм, когда пытаюсь сменить - отказ.

[image: скрин]

Comment: а как вы меняете? какой командой?

Comment: да, как фотку прикрепить ? В сообщении мне казалось, я прикрепил скрин. Нет никакого сообщения, просто остается в том же диске

Comment: лучше текстом. Так можно скопировать чуть что.

Comment: вообще ставлю на то, что ключ /d забыли

Comment: Исходное положение:
C:\ 
далее
C:\ cd d:\
выдает
c:\

Comment: Добавляйте в вопрос (ссылка "править" под ним), а не комментариями.

Comment: диск меняется без `cd`, просто `d:\\` пишите и все

Comment: просто d:\ не получилось

Comment: CD - это **C**hange **D**irectory. А ни фига не change drive. Для смены текущего диска используется просто его указание: `C:\> d:<Enter>`. Для одновременной смены и диска, и каталога - используется команда CD с ключом /D: `c:\> CD /D d:\tmp<Enter>`

Comment: Господа, спасибо! Вопрос решен.